# How to create a unique key extractor for three items in flatlist

Tags: react-native

I am using react native flatList, and I am creating 3 columns within one render item. The reason I am not using numColumns is because i want 2 columns when the phone is portrait and 3 when it is landscape. However, numcolumns refuses to change dynamically and throws an error. I have to create a unique id for the three items, so if any of the three items change, the entire row changes. If I use val.id, unless the first item changes, the rest don't. Each of the three items rendering have a number id that is distinct. An additional caveat is that sometimes it might 2 or 1 items being rendered, so I can't use a string combined version of the ids because 936 could be one id while the two other ids are 93 and 6 and that would mean the keys are not unique. How could I create a unique key extractor for the three items. The reason I mentioned that it is react native and what I am trying to accomplish is because I am open to other solutions that would allow me to render a dynamic number of columns based on the orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change the number of columns dynamically, I assume that this error gets thrown

`Changing numColumns on the fly is not supported. Change the key prop on the flatlist, when changing the number of columns to force a fresh render of the component`.

As the error suggests, you need to use the `key` prop on the flatlist to change the `numcolumns` dynamically. You can try the following.

When the orientation changes, detect it and set the state accordingly, to change the value of numColumns. This will cause the key prop on the flatlist to change and trigger a rerender of the list. Refer this pseudo code.

```js
  onOrientationChange = () => {

    if (orientation === 'portrait') { // replace this with actual logic.

      this.setState({numColumns: 2 });

     } else if (orientation === 'landscape') {

        this.setState({ numColumns: 3 }); 
    }

  }

  <FlatList
     key={this.state.numColumns}
     numColumns={this.state.numColumns}
     ...
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make flatlist keys unique, then use timestamp

```
<FlatList
        data={sessions}
        renderItem={({item})=><RenderCard item={item} />}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>item.sessionID+new Date()}
     />
```